C++ deduction guide for std::expected and other "wrapped" return types
Wondering if there is a way to write a template deduction guide that will allow Func0 code to compile in the following example.
#include <string>
#include <expected>

struct s
{
    int n1 = 0;
    int n2 = 0;
};

namespace std
{
// Attempt at some deduction guide to allow Func0 to compile, but it changes nothing.
// Only Func1 Func2 styles work here.
// Not, I am not trying to write more optimal codew but rather looking for a way
// to write simpler return cases when returning some value within a templated wrapper
// could be expected, optional, ...
// This partly refers to C++ weekly ep 421 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0yJk5yfdih0)
expected(int, int) -> expected<int, int>;

// Compilation errors here.
/*
expected<s, string> Func0()
{
    return {1, 2};
}
*/

expected<s, string> Func1()
{
    return {{1, 2}};
}

expected<s, string> Func2()
{
    s news{1, 2};
    return news;
}

expected<s, string> Func3()
{
    return unexpected{"error string"};
}

}   // namespace std

int main()
{

}

The Func1 style works fine and is simple enough to write, but I'd like to avoid the nested {{}} if possible and so far, deduction guides didn't help me here.
Are deduction guides a viable solution here to support return {1, 2}; or is the only solution atm to make some make_expected() helper function (like make_pair).
thanks
I tried various way to type the return values of my test Func0-1-2.
Was expecting a guide like this to work
expected(int, int) -> expected<int, int>;

Why not return s{1, 2}; If you find the type too long (not in the example, obviously), abbreviate it with using.

It's undefined behavior to extend the namespace std

yes that's just for test purposes, I have struct similar to expected in some code base, I just reproduced with some more public types and code here, but the results are the same

I agree some alias to shorten the type can be useful sometimes, it is not the goal here. I'm really wondering if the very simple {1, 2} case is possible with deduction guides. Maybe some fancier template magic using in_place_t, cause the goal is also to avoid unneeded constructors.
Avoid tried yet as I just thought of it now, but maybe something like this could work ? Dunno if that compiles, just a raw idea atm.
expected(int, int) -> expected<in_place_t, int, int>

Your deduction guide is wrong. expected<int,int>::expected(in,int) does not exist. The error type is also not deducible from initializer for value; So the request is flawed in the first place. If you fix the error type: template<typename V> using result=std::expected<V, std::error_condition>; then at least a make_result function is possible. Deduction for aliase type has (I guess) platform-dependent support.

You are right, the attempted guide here doesn't match the intented result at all. expected<int, int> a{1}; compiles fine but has nothing to do with my desired final result type which is expected<s, string>.
Since expected<int, int> would make the error type (arg 2) be of type int, while I was using string type in my example.
So we're left with either {{1, 2}} or a make_expected helper as most simple way to type this. Unless someone comes up with a way to do the "return {1, 2};" (i.e. remove the { } nested.
thanks
